# OpenCV Tracker property access fails with SEGFAULT on ARM, but works in X86_64

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to port my application to a raspberry pi 4, but had no luck with trackers. I basically use a tracker as a class member. While this works on my Ubuntu machine, it causes a segmentation fault in raspberry. I reproduced the problem with this minimal working example (it does not make any sense, but depict exactly my problem). I'm using OpenCV 4.3.0 with support for INFERENCE ENGINE for both (in the raspberry I built it using the docker as indicated in the documentation). Segmentation fault occurs when I try to access the tracker properties (getDefaultName).. I cannot understand why this works on my computer and fails on the raspberry (I also add that the tracker example in the OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html) works)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    person p;
    p.createTracker("mosse");
    if (p.tracker){
        cout << "not null" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "null" << endl;
    }
    cout << p.tracker->getDefaultName();
    return 0;
}
```

person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracker.hpp>

class person
{
public:
    person();
    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker;

    void createTracker(std::string type);

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

person.cpp

```
#include "person.h"

person::person()
{
}

void person::createTracker(std::string type)
{

    if(type== "mosse") {
        tracker = cv::TrackerMOSSE::create();
    } else if(type == "csrt")
        tracker = cv::TrackerCSRT::create();
    else if(type == "kcf")
        tracker = cv::TrackerKCF::create();
    else if(type == "tld")
        tracker = cv::TrackerTLD::create();
    else {
        std::cout << "Tracking type not specified! This should not happen.";
    }
```

EDIT
"not null" is printed

EDIT 2

Putting everything inside main function works as expected. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/tracking/tracking.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "Hello" << endl;

    cv::Ptr<cv::Tracker> tracker = cv::TrackerMOSSE::create();

    cout << tracker->getDefaultName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `tracker` is a `nullptr`?  You should check this before assuming it is pointing somewhere valid.

Comment: I just checked and it's not nullptr (editing question).. I want also to add that this is the complete MWE, nothing else, which works in my machine but segfault in raspberry..

Comment: What data type is returned from `getDefaultName()`?  Is it `std::string`?

Comment: virtual std::string .. I'm running other tests and the problem is only with "mosse" so I suspect It can be a bug of OpenCV..

Comment: Just wanted you to be sure that your application's version of `std::string` is using the same heap as the `std::string` being returned to you.  If not, then that would be one reason for the behavior you're seeing.  If that `std::string` is coming from a DLL, then that makes it more susceptible to memory corruption issues if the app was not built with certain options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in Opencv 4.3.0, I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2546) but it's still unanswered, I don't know if it's been fixed. Anyway same code works in OpenCV 3.4.10 and fails in 4.1.2 confirming my idea, something should have broke from version 4.

**EDIT**
As of April 23, 2021 bug is still there with version 4.5.2, I opened a new issue [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2930).